# Can I restore a SQL Server instance from file backups only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, windows, windows-server-2016

Our windows 2016 server failed to restart after a windows update yesterday.

In order to avoid the update that crashed it issue (whatever it was), I'm in the process of rebuilding it clean.

So I've reinstalled Windows Server 2016, and SQL Server 2016 (same version we were using before).

I have a full system backup from a couple of days ago viz Windows SErver Backup.

What I am having a hard time finding is information on

**"How do I restore a SQL Server instance directly from Win Backup files?"**

I have recreated the same named instance we had before (so that the file paths match, etc.) - but I have no idea how to make that work?  Can it possibly be as simple as shutting down SQL Server temporarily - using Windows Backup to restore the necessary C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SOURCEGEARVAULT\?

Or is there more to it than that?  If so, where can I find instructions for this?

If I had a true backup of the database - and not simply the filesystem - I would have access to lots of how-to's - I've done that before.  But I don't have that - I just have the raw filesystem a day before it died.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

UPDATE: per feedback - moved this to: https://serverfault.com/questions/914463/can-i-restore-a-sql-server-instance-from-file-backups-only

Comment: As an aside, it would be far, far simpler to roll back the machine to the previous known good state; there's no guarantee that a clean rebuild (which, as you've discovered, takes quite a bit of effort) isn't going to run into exactly the same problem before long, let alone the problems it will run into for not being exactly the same instance as before. So if a rollback isn't possible now (for whatever reason) consider investing in things so it will be possible in the future.

Comment: You might be able to attach the database using the db files. I would suggest that once you get this solved you revisit your disaster recovery strategy. It sounds like you only did step one (creating backups). Step two is the critical piece that most people miss. This is the recovery strategy. This is where you plan and practice data recovery using the backups from step one. The time to learn this stuff is not during an outage.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).